# Notion of distance algorithm behavior

Tags: probability-distributions, algorithms, python

I have currently implemented the solution of Hellinger Distance in Node.js and Python.

The Hellinger Distance is being calculated over two histograms p and q. They are normalized discrete probability distributions.

However, consider this:

```
p = [0, 0, 0, i, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
q0 = [0, 0, 0, 0, j, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

h(p, q0) = x0
```

Furthermore:

```
p = [0, 0, 0, i, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
q1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, j]

h(p, q1) = x1
```

Here I would prefer that the distance value of x1 should be greater than x0. But when I test this I get the exact same distance.

Is there any other algorithm I could implement that could solve this issue together with the Hellinger Distance?

Real example with HD:

```
p = [50.00, 50.00, 94.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00]
q0 = [50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 94.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00]

h(p, q0) = 0.19724284169529102


p = [50.00, 50.00, 94.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00]
q1 = [50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 94.00]

h(p, q1) = 0.19724284169529102
```

The implementation is done in a straight forward way following the function for hellinger distance:

$$h(p, q) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k(\sqrt{p_i} - \sqrt{q_i})²}$$

Note that both p and q are normalized before being sent as argument to the hellinger distance function.

As far as I understand, this is a correct output from the algorithm.

Right now I am investigating the earth mover algorithm.

But I am happy to take any answer that could lead me to a suitable algorithm.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question exactly? There is no problem with the results...

Comment: Well i do believe there is a problem with the result, not that it is incorrect. I need to adapt the function so that it can detect this kind of change, if you look at distance value returned by the function for q1. I think that it should be a different value, because the vectors are not the same, but it contains the same values.

I may be wrong but I want it to be able to detect this.

Comment: You should edit your question. It is not about algorithms. You are looking for a notion of distance ir divergence between probability distributions that has a specific behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have modified my question.